# __abstractmethods__ and AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was playing with the `dir()` builtin function when I noticed this:

```
>>> dir(type)
['__abstractmethods__', '__base__', '__bases__', '__basicsize__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dictoffset__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__flags__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__instancecheck__', '__itemsize__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mro__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__prepare__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__', '__weakrefoffset__', 'mro']
>>> type.__abstractmethods__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __abstractmethods__
>>> list.__abstractmethods__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __abstractmethods__
```

I don't understand, it appears in the list, why am I getting such error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`__abstractmethods__` is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) to support [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html); it wraps a *slot* that is empty by default (so the descriptor raises an attribute error). Most of all, it is an implementation detail of how CPython handles abstract methods.

The attribute is used to track what methods are abstract, so that instances can be blocked from being created if they don't provide concrete implementations:

```
>>> import abc
>>> class FooABC(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> FooABC.__abstractmethods__
frozenset({'bar'})
>>> class Foo(FooABC): pass
... 
>>> Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Foo with abstract methods bar
```

The `abc.ABCMeta` implementation sets the `__abstractmethods__` attribute, and `type()` uses it to check for any abstract methods that should have been implemented but are not.

Comment: Wasn't it more consistent if `__abstractmethods__` returned empty frozenset by default?

Comment: Why would an internal implementation detail have to do that? Why waste the memory on a `frozenset()` for something only a small number of classes use?

Comment: It might be more consistent if `dir` didn't return the name of something that would result in an `AttributeError` if accessed, but `dir` is documented as not necessarily being consistent.