# How does this use of Python's __metaclass__ work?

Tags: python, class, metaprogramming

[Here in this IPython Notebook](https://gist.github.com/dutc/4eb5124bda88eedd476e) I found a presentation about generators and functional programming. I stumbled upon `__metaclass__`:

1. Why are `Real` and `float` arguments of `Accounting`? What usually is there now is in `bases`, but is it required to write `Real` and `float` in there?
2. What does `__abstractmethods__` do? I cannot find it in the usual list of special methods.
3. Does the author enrich his `Accounting` class with methods from other classes by using those two for loops?
4. Why does `Accounting(getattr(float,meth)(*args, **kwargs))`not result in an infinite loop? What happens here in contrast to the second version?

**First, this is the excerpt which is relevant for my question:**

```
class Accounting(Real, float):
    def __metaclass__(name, bases, body):
        for method in Real.__abstractmethods__:
            if method not in body:
                body[method] = (lambda meth: lambda *args, **kwargs: Accounting(getattr(float,meth)(*args, **kwargs)))(method)
        for method in ('__ne__','__nonzero__',):
            if method not in body:
                body[method] = (lambda meth: lambda *args, **kwargs: getattr(float,meth)(*args, **kwargs))(method)
        return Real.__metaclass__(name, bases, body)
    __new__ = float.__new__
```

**This is the whole code:**

```
from numbers import Real
class Accounting(Real, float):
    def __metaclass__(name, bases, body):
        for method in Real.__abstractmethods__:
            if method not in body:
                body[method] = (lambda meth: lambda *args, **kwargs: Accounting(getattr(float,meth)(*args, **kwargs)))(method)
        for method in ('__ne__','__nonzero__',):
            if method not in body:
                body[method] = (lambda meth: lambda *args, **kwargs: getattr(float,meth)(*args, **kwargs))(method)
        return Real.__metaclass__(name, bases, body)
    __new__ = float.__new__
    def __format__(self, fmt):        
        return { 1: ' %s'%float.__format__(self, fmt),
                 0: ' %s'%float.__format__(self, fmt).replace('0', '-'),
                -1: '(%s)'%float.__format__(self, fmt) }[cmp(self,0)]
```

The code is then used here:

```
template = '{region:<{align}}   {profit:>14,.0f}'.format
def output(markets, write=print, template=template):
    align = max(map(len,markets))
    for region, profit in markets.items():
        line = template(region=region, profit=profit, align=align)
        write(line)

output({region:Accounting(profit) for region, profit in markets.items()})
```

Output:

```
Central America   (      -675,140)
US                (    -2,724,620)
Antarctica                      -
Asia              (    -3,614,396)
UK                (    -2,380,001)
EU                        771,665
CEMEA                   3,480,172
```

Comment: If you don't understand metaclass, you don't need metaclass :)

Comment: Here's some information on [**`__abstractmethods__`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24914634/355230).

Comment: Also see **[Python-Dev: inconsistent __abstractmethods__ behavior; lack of documentation](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2011-August/112755.html)**.

Comment: The use of metaclasses here looks like an unneccessarily complex method of over-riding the __format__ method - but maybe there is something else here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one part of the answer :

```
for method in Real.__abstractmethods__:
           if method not in body:
               body[method] = (lambda meth: lambda *args, **kwargs: Accounting(getattr(float,meth)(*args, **kwargs)))(method)
```

numbers.Real is an abstract class (i.e. you can't substantiate an instance of it, but you can use it as a subclass. The Real class has a special frozenset called `__abstractmethods__` which seems to list all of the methods which the Real class expects to be defined. :

in the interactive interpreter :

```
from numbers import Real
Real.__abstractmethods__
frozenset(['__rtruediv__', '__radd__', '__truediv__', '__pow__', '__add__', '__rdiv__', '__rmul__', '__rmod__', '__eq__', '__lt__', '__float__', '__rpow__', '__mod__', '__trunc__', '__abs__', '__pos__', '__div__', '__le__', '__rfloordiv__', '__neg__', '__floordiv__', '__mul__'])
```

This loop therefore is ensuring that the body (which is the class actually being created by the metaclass), has a concrete definition for each of these methods.

I will admit I don't fully grok the nested lambda definition though.

Comment: Yes, the lambda definition is hard to understand -- especially without seeing the source for the `Real` class. What it appears to do is instantiate a separate `Accounting` object (while creating the `Accounting` class!), and then pass then method the results of calling the corresponding `float` method with the arguments supplied, and finally pass that result to that temporary `Accounting` object's `__call__()` method.